# Reduce display element from choice list Django

Tags: python, django

I have a question about my project and I think I need some advices in order to get the expected result.

I created a individual formulary which works very well and now I want to create my BirthCertificate Form. The second one takes values from the first one as following :

[image]

But, to my mind the problem is situated with `ID Parent1` and `ID Parent2`. This field displays all values for each row but I would like to make different :

- First solution : I display all rows but just `Lastname` `Firstname` `Birthdate`
- Second solution : I try to make a research bar letting to get `Parent1` and `Parent2`

The problem is : How I can do that ?

This is my **models.py file** :

```
class BirthCertificate(models.Model):

    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, verbose_name='Nom de famille')
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, verbose_name='Prénom(s)')
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEX_CHOICES, verbose_name='Sexe')
    birthday = models.DateField(null=False, verbose_name='Date de naissance')
    birthhour = models.TimeField(null=True, verbose_name='Heure de naissance')
    birthcity = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, verbose_name='Ville de naissance')
    birthcountry = models.ForeignKey(Country, related_name='Pays_Naissance', verbose_name='Pays de naissance')
    fk_parent1 = models.ForeignKey(Identity, related_name='ID_Parent1', verbose_name='ID parent1', null=True)
    fk_parent2 = models.ForeignKey(Identity, related_name='ID_Parent2', verbose_name='ID parent2', null=True)
```

This is my **forms.py file** :

```
from django import forms
from BirthCertificate.models import *

class BirthCertificateForm(forms.ModelForm) :

    class Meta :
        model = BirthCertificate
        fields = '__all__'
```

Then, the function from **views.py file** which let to create and fill the formulary :

```
def BirthCertificate_Form(request) :
    # Fonction permettant de créer le formulaire Acte de Naissance et le remplissage

    Bform = BirthCertificateForm(request.POST or None) 

    if Bform.is_valid() :   # Vérification sur la validité des données
        Bform.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('formulaire_traite')

    context = {
        "Bform" : Bform,
        }

    return render(request, 'birthform.html', context)
```

Thank you so much !

**EDIT :**

I add my models.py file from Identity Apps :

```
class Identity(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=12,choices=TITLE_CHOICES, verbose_name='Civilité')
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Nom de famille')
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Prénom(s)')
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEX_CHOICES, verbose_name='sexe')
    birthday = models.DateField(verbose_name='Date de naissance')
    birthcity = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Ville de naissance')
    birthcountry = models.ForeignKey(Country, related_name='Pays_naissance', verbose_name='Pays de Naissance')
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Nationalité')
    job = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Profession')
    adress = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Adresse')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Ville')
    zip = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Code Postal')
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, related_name='Pays1', verbose_name='Pays')
    mail = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Email', blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Téléphone', blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s' % (self.id, self.title, self.lastname, self.firstname, self.sex, self.birthday, self.birthcity, self.birthcountry,
                                                                    self.nationality, self.job, self.adress, self.city, self.zip, self.country, self.mail, self.phone)
```

and the template :

```
<!--DOCTYPE html -->
<html>

<body>

<h1 align="center"> Formulaire d'acte de naissance </h1>

<form method='POST' action=''> {% csrf_token %}

<h3> Partie contenant les informations de l'enfant</h3>
{{ Bform.as_ul}} <!-- Display child part formulary -->
{{ value|date:"%d/%m/%Y" }}
{{ value|time:"H:M" }}

<br></br>

<input type ="submit" value="Valider le formulaire" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Inside my Identity Application, I need to show all elements from this table. But I only want to display few elements from this model to my BirthCertificate App ;)

Comment: Show us the code of Identity model. Then I might be able to help you.

Comment: I added the code of Identity model. Just one precision, in my Identity App, I need to display all elements, that's why I made 16 `%s`

Comment: For solution 1, you could just change the `unicode` method of  `Identity` if that doesn't break stuff elsewhere.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Yes, but as I said, I need to display all elements in my Identity App. Can I separate elements displayed between 2 apps in the same method ? Otherside, solution 2 seems faster and better. Maybe I need to go on this way. I just have no idea to do that (I'm beginning Django)

Comment: Can you, please, share the code of your template? It's not clear how you display all your fields.

Comment: @Fomalhaut Sure, it's very simple for the moment. I added it ;)

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi Ok, I didn't learn widgets for the moment, but I will look How I can do that !

Comment: Try creating a custom field inhereted from ModelChoiceField and redefine  ModelChoiceIterator, but it's not an easy way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create custom model field

```
from django.utils.encoding import force_text

class CustomLabelModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._label_from_instance = kwargs.pop('label_func', force_text)
        super(CustomLabelModelChoiceField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return self._label_from_instance(obj)
```

Add this field to your model. There is a disadvantage because your need to manually synchronize model field with form field.

```
class BirthCertificateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    fk_parent1 = CustomLabelModelChoiceField(Identity.objects.all(), required=False, label="ID parent1", label_func=lambda obj: '%s %s %s' % (obj.firstname, obj.lastname, obj.birthday))
    fk_parent2 = CustomLabelModelChoiceField(Identity.objects.all(), required=False, label="ID parent2", label_func=lambda obj: '%s %s %s' % (obj.firstname, obj.lastname, obj.birthday))

    class Meta :
        model = BirthCertificate
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Oh ok I see ! I just have an error : `class CustomLabelModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
NameError: name 'ModelChoiceField' is not defined` I'm looking for to solve it

Comment: First one goes to models.py and the second one to forms.py right ?

Comment: No, it's all for forms.py.

Comment: Ok ! So, I just have to change the displayed field name (because it's written `Fk parent1` and `Fk parent2`)

Comment: Add label to customized form fields. (i've updated the code)

Comment: I replaced `Identity.objects.all` by `Identity.objects.filter(sex="M")` where fk_parent1 is `label="Père(Father in english)"`

Answer (score 1):

Try updating **widgets** of your ModelForm. 
You can do something like this :

```
class BirthCertificateForm(forms.ModelForm) :

    class Meta :
        model = BirthCertificate
        fields = '__all__'
        identityObj = [[x.firstname, x.lastname ,x.birthday] for x in Identity.objects.all()] 

        widgets = {
            'fk_parent1': forms.Select(choices=identityObj),
            'fk_parent2': forms.Select(choices=identityObj)

        }
```

Comment: So with this solution, I could display only 3 elements by row (as expected) and get it as a choice list ?

Comment: Yeah,I hope so.

Comment: I tried it, but I don't see any modifications ^^ I'm looking why